# Where does InstallCert.java get the server certificates

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl-certificate, keytool

I'm attempting to follow the instructions on this page:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/
to create a certificate for my localhost in which to do some development testing.

When running InstallCert for localhost:8443, the following two certificates are generated:

> Server sent 2 certificate(s):
>
> 1 Subject CN=localhost4.localdomain4, O=example.com, C=US
>     Issuer  CN=Certificate Shack, O=example.com, C=US
>     sha1    f4 2a a9 09 32 a6 ee 41 9d 9c 44 e6 4a bc 31 79 17 cb 88 fd 
>     md5     e0 78 65 83 30 33 78 c5 80 17 e7 7a a2 91 85 52
>
> 2 Subject CN=Certificate Shack, O=example.com, C=US
>     Issuer  CN=Certificate Shack, O=example.com, C=US
>     sha1    b8 87 d6 2d ac d8 36 06 7c 58 68 10 3e 21 39 6a a0 33 a1 25 
>     md5     07 24 57 5f f8 35 1e 97 70 ff 54 aa 13 e6 6b 12

The trouble is that my system needs the CN to be localhost. I have no idea where the localhost4.localdomain4 comes from. How can I change this to be simply localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The certificate comes from the server, during the handshake.
2. The CN is inside the certificate.
3. You can't change it without creating a new server certificate.

Comment: I've attempted to add a new server certificate, but it never seems to show up.

Comment: You would need to restart any JVMs you want it to show up in, so they re-read the truststore.